# Windows batch: Check for highest folder prefix and create new project folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, increment

In the past I found plenty of solutions just by searching StackOverflow's discussion history. However, I am stuck with this batch file, (as Windows scripting is not something I generally do).

The current directory contains many subfolders (in reality many thousands), see this example:

```
18.01.2023  10:05    <DIR>          .
18.01.2023  08:49    <DIR>          ..
18.01.2023  10:02    <DIR>          1-Lion
18.01.2023  10:02    <DIR>          2-Fox
18.01.2023  10:03    <DIR>          126-Orion (prior folders deleted)
18.01.2023  10:03    <DIR>          127-Future
18.01.2023  10:05    <DIR>          Random folder without prefix
18.01.2023  10:01               708 test.bat
               1 Datei(en),            708 Bytes
               7 Verzeichnis(se),
```

The next project hence shall have the prefix `128`, in the above example.

I want the script to check all existing folders for the numeric prefixes. Those prefixes can be `1` to `99999`, i.e. up to five numeric characters and is separated from the rest of the name by the character `-`. *(Some folders might not have any numeric prefix, those should be ignored)*.

The script should then create a new folder with the next "available" prefix as project number.

Here is what I tried:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Set initial value for MaxPrefix variable
set MaxPrefix=0

rem Check all existing folders in current directory
for /D %%F in (*) do (
    rem Check if folder name has numeric prefix
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=-" %%P in ("%%F") do (
        rem Check if prefix is higher than current MaxPrefix value
        if %%P GTR %MaxPrefix% set MaxPrefix=%%P
    )
)

rem Ask for new project name
set /p projectname=Enter new project name:

rem Reject input if empty
if "%projectname%" == "" (
    echo Invalid input, project name cannot be empty.
    pause
    exit
)

rem Check if project name already exists as folder label
for /D %%F in (*) do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%P in ("%%F") do (
        if /I "%%P" == "%projectname%" (
            echo Project already exists with project number %MaxPrefix%.
            pause
            exit
        )
    )
)

rem Create new folder with incremented MaxPrefix and project name
set /a newprefix=%MaxPrefix% + 1
md %newprefix%-%projectname%

echo New project created with project number %newprefix%.
pause
```

My approach for the prefix "detection" does not seem to work, hence also the correct creation is failing, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

SET /a nextprefix=1

FOR /f "tokens=1delims=-" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO CALL :process "%%e"

ECHO Next prefix is %nextprefix%

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "$=9%~1"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "$=%%$:%%z=%%"
IF DEFINED $ GOTO :eof
IF %~1 geq %nextprefix% SET /a nextprefix=%~1+1
GOTO :eof
```

Note that this routine only calculates the next prefix.

List the directories, grab the part of the name before the `-`, quote it and pass to `:process`.

Within `:process`, prefix the passed string with `9`, then remove each of the digits. If the result is that the string is not empty, then there are other characters in the string, so ignore it.

Otherwise, if the string's value is >= current next-value, set next-value to 1 more than the value of the string.

`9` is prefixed to the string in order that the string never becomes empty until the very last substitution.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Magoo I got my batch working. I am posting the edited code below, maybe someone has use for it. Thanks again!

```
@echo off


rem Codepage Einstellung auf ANSI für deutsche Umlaute
chcp 1252>nul

echo.
echo.
echo M&A Filestruktur Generator
echo Dr. Hans-Friedrich Fuge, Stand 10/01/2023
echo.
echo.



setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Find the next "free" Prefix as new project number

SET /a nextprefix=1

FOR /f "tokens=1delims=-" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /ad *" '
 ) DO CALL :process "%%e"

GOTO :Neuprojekt

:process
SET "$=9%~1"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "$=%%$:%%z=%%"
IF DEFINED $ GOTO :eof
IF %~1 geq %nextprefix% SET /a nextprefix=%~1+1
GOTO :eof

:Neuprojekt
rem Ask for new project name
set /p projectname=Wie lautet das neue Projekt (idealerweise Format PROJEKTNAME-UNTERNEHMENSNAME):

rem Reject input if empty
if "%projectname%" == "" (
echo.
echo Ungültige Eingabe, es muß ein Projektname eingegeben werden.
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
)

rem Check if project name already exists as folder label
for /D %%F in (*) do (
for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%P in ("%%F") do (
if /I "%%P" == "%projectname%" (
echo.
echo.
echo Der Projektname exitiert bereits als %%F.
pause
exit
)
)
)

rem Create new folder with incremented Prefix and project name
md %nextprefix%-"%projectname%"
cd %nextprefix%-"%projectname%"

rem Erstellung der Unterordner Struktur

md Prozess
md Offers
md "Due diligence"
md Financials
md Legal
md alt

cd Prozess
md NDA
md IM
md MP
md "Process letter"
cd..

cd Offers
md "Indicative offer"
md "Binding offer"
cd Indicative offer
md alt
cd..
cd Binding offer
md alt
cd..
cd..

cd Due diligence
md Templates
md Research
md "Data room"
cd..

cd Financials
md Dealsheet
md Model
cd Model
md alt
cd..
md "Other financials"
cd..

cd legal
md SPA
cd SPA
md alt
cd..
md "Other legal"
cd..


echo.
echo Es wurde eine neue Projektstruktur unter %nextprefix%-"%projectname%" erstellt.
echo.
endlocal
pause
```